# Grouping words in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I have a dataframe column with different device models. I want to generate summary for common models by grouping similar devices together. I don't have a list of exact brands/words to use difflib SequenceMatcher.

***Main challenge I'm facing***: - I don't have a fixed list of products (devices) - it's a million rows long data frame with devices ranging from Playstations and Nintendos to all the phones and tablets.

This is how my data looks like:

| device_model | volume of requests (100k) |
| --- | --- |
| iphone XR | 1.6151 |
| ipad | 1.4768 |
| galaxy s21 5g | 1.4443 |
| ultra 5g galaxy s21 | 1.3395 |
| samsung galaxy s9 | 1.2902 |
| iphone 11 | 1.2696 |
| galaxy s10 | 1.2613 |
| a32 5g galaxy | 1.209 |
| galaxy s10e | 1.0994 |
| apple iphone 13 pro max | 1.0285 |
| a12 galaxy | 1.0089 |
| galaxy s22 ultra 5g | 1.0054 |
| samsung galaxy s20 fe 5g | 0.9686 |
| iphone 13 pro | 0.9116 |
| galaxy s10+ | 0.8795 |
| S22 galaxy 5g | 0.8279 |
| galaxy s9 plus | 0.8175 |
| 5g galaxy s21 plus | 0.8155 |
| apple ipad air | 0.7958 |

**This is how I would like my output to be**

| device_model | total request volume (100k) |
| --- | --- |
| iPhone | 4.8248 |
| iPad | 2.2726 |
| Galaxy | 13.967 |

I tried to apply topic modelling using Spacy & Gensim, and N-grams, but it doesn't work reliably for such small words. Looking for a quick and simple way.

Comment: I think the main problem is to extract the device name from column `device_model`. The output can than be created by `df.groupby('device')['volume of requests (100k)'].sum()`

Comment: yes of course, that's the key problem I'm facing. Summing up is not an issue. I'm not able to group the words/devices together.

Comment: @NuriTaş, as mentioned in my question's bold faced text,

Main challenge I'm facing - I don't have a fixed list of products (devices) - it's a million rows long data frame with devices ranging from Playstations and Nintendos to all the phones and tablets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a neat solution (I think), loved the puzzle:

It finds the most common word in the column and assign this word as device for the rows where the most common word appears. Then, for the remaining rows, it finds the most common word and assigns this word as device for these rows. This repeats untill the complete column `device` is filled.

```
from collections import Counter

df['device'] = ''

while sum(df['device'] == '') > 0:
    most_common_word = Counter(" ".join(df[df['device'] == '']["device_model"]).split()).most_common(1)[0][0]
    df.loc[df.device_model.str.contains(most_common_word) & (df.device == ''), 'device'] = most_common_word
    print(most_common_word)
```

Returns:

```
galaxy
iphone
ipad
```

Then apply `pd.groupby`:

```
df.groupby('device')['volume of requests (100k)'].sum()
```

Output:

```
device
galaxy    13.9670
ipad       2.2726
iphone     4.8248
Name: volume of requests (100k), dtype: float64
```

Note that this does not work when (for example) the word pro is the most common word which is quite possible. However for the dataset given, it works. These über common words need to be removed first, otherwise it is quite hard for a program to know that pro is not a device

Comment: while it works for less common words like nord or fire stick, I'm getting issues with the most common devices. its returning 's' for galaxy s10 etc. and pad for ipad.

```Device_Models Volume device
     iphone 30.4737 one
     ipad 4.7420 pad
     galaxy s21 5g 2.3672 s
     galaxy s21 ultra 5g 1.6570 s
     galaxy s9 1.6151 s```

Comment: Do words like `pad` and `s` appear in your column with device models?

Comment: no, the data looks like this preview I provided in the question - I took it directly from my data as is. I think because of `Galaxy S10` - it's counting `S` as most repeated words ignoring the numbers associated with it. no clue about pad though. It was just `ipad` which is shown as `pad` in the results.

Comment: When I use your dataset above, it does not count `s` as a seperate word but for example `s21` and `s9` are words

Comment: alright, not sure where the problem is. What are you getting returned for the output?

Comment: btw which counter is this? 
I've used `from collections import Counter`

Comment: What do you get when you run `Counter(" ".join(df["device_model"]).split()).most_common(100)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248289/discussion-between-lightyagami96-and-t-c-molenaar).